# how can get spinner values when I used if else then pass value to setonClick?

Tags: android, android-spinner

how can get spinner values when I used if else then pass value to setonClick?

in my code, I used this methods to set spinner values

```
DatabaseReference chk_sub  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()......
chk_sub.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
if(xxxxxx){
List<String> sub = new ArrayList<>();
sub.add(0, getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.choose_sub));
sub.add("USA");
sub.add("CA");
ArrayAdapter<String> dataSpinnerAdapter;
dataSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplication(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sub);
                    dataSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataSpinnerAdapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.choose_sub))){
    //do nothing
} else {
    spinner_item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Selected : "+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
}
```

and I hope I can get spinner sub value because I need to judge

```
post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if( --  how can get spinner value in here? --){
                   //  
                }else {
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.must_upload), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want selected spinner item to be used in if(condition=spinner value) on click event of post i.e., post.onClick(), just get the spinner selected item

your code will look like this

```
post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("your compare value")){
                   // do whatever you want
                }else {
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.must_upload), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```